# building design matrix of random effects in a LMM

Tags: mixed-model, experiment-design, simulation, matrix

I am working in simulations of data following a LMM. The general formula of the model, as defined in most texts books is as follows:

$$Y=X\beta+Zb+\epsilon$$

Where $b\sim N(0,D)$, $\epsilon \sim N(0,R)$, $X$ is a design matrix of fixed effects and $Z$ is a design matrix of random effects.The most common way to define $Z$ is using a block diagonal representation, for example:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Z_1 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & Z_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & Z_N
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However this representation is only valid if we assume that the data itself is ordered also (measurements of the same subject are put together if we use as an example a longitudinal study). If this ordering is not maintained, $Z$ could not be represented as bloc diagonal anymore. Let me show this, for a very simple example, and for the sake of simplicity I am going to generate the design matrices in R:

```
my_n<-5
#data.frame with data
z0<-expand.grid(id=(1:my_n) %>% factor,time=c(1:5))
# z0<-z0[order(z0$id,z0$time),]

#partial design matrix for random intercept
Z0<-model.matrix(~-1+ id, z0)
#partial design matrix for slopes
Z1<-diag(z0$time)%*%Z0

#full design matrix for random effects
Z<-NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(Z0)){
  Z<-cbind(Z,Z0[,i],Z1[,i])
}
Z
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1     1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
2     0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
3     0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0     0
4     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0
5     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
6     1    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
7     0    0    1    2    0    0    0    0    0     0
8     0    0    0    0    1    2    0    0    0     0
9     0    0    0    0    0    0    1    2    0     0
10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     2
11    1    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
12    0    0    1    3    0    0    0    0    0     0
13    0    0    0    0    1    3    0    0    0     0
14    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    3    0     0
15    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     3
16    1    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
17    0    0    1    4    0    0    0    0    0     0
18    0    0    0    0    1    4    0    0    0     0
19    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    4    0     0
20    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     4
21    1    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
22    0    0    1    5    0    0    0    0    0     0
23    0    0    0    0    1    5    0    0    0     0
24    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    5    0     0
25    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     5
```

If you uncomment line `z0<-z0[order(z0$id,z0$time),]` we get a bloc diagonal matrix as is commonly presented.

The question is simple: how to build a design matrix for random effects in a a LMM in a cleaner way (hopefully using matrix algebra operations) regardless of the order of the data?

Here I add some code to show the final result of the simulation:

```
#random effects b0 dsitribution and simulation
D_i<-matrix(c(1.3,0.5,0.5,0.3),nrow = 2)
D<-kronecker(diag(rep(1,my_n)),D_i)
bs<-rmvnorm(1,rep(0,nrow(D)),D)

#random effects e
sd_e<-1.3
e<-rnorm(nrow(z0),0,sd_e)

#fixed effects parameters
my_bts<-c(10,1.4)
#model matrix
z0_mat <- model.matrix(~ time, z0)
# expected values
Xbeta<-z0_mat%*%my_bts
Zb<-Z%*%t(bs)
z0$y<-(Xbeta+Zb+e) %>% drop
```

to estimate parameters I use the following code

```
m0<-lme(y~time,random = ~1+time|id,data=z0)
summary(m0)
getVarCov(m0,individual =1 )
```

I suggest using a bigger value of `my_n` before doing this.

Surprisingly (at least for me), it seems that covariance matrix $D$ is not affected by the ordering of the data and it has (always?) the same block diagonal structure, regardless of ordering of data in data frame `z0`, at least for this case.

I would love if some one have references discussing this topic from a computational perspective, not only for design matrices for random effects in LMM but also on correlation matrices as well for this kind of models.

This work is based on this [text](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-3900-4)

Comment: I guess a quick solution would be something like `Z <- model.matrix(~ 0 + id + id:time, z0); Z <- Z[, order(colnames(Z))]`

Comment: @statmerkur thanks for the feedback. You should post this as an answer, at least is better than using a for loop.